# Why is hashtable count = 1 and not =5?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to read and split 5-items into a hashtable.
But I only get one pair in the hashtable.

```
$h=@{}
@"
c : A P L
R : 6h
H : HN-56-78
L : binary
E : m@a.com
"@ | %{ $v,$k = $_ -replace ' ' -split ':' ; $h.Add($v,$k) }
$h.Count
```

Comment: Just double checking... are you planning to read this input from a file?  Or are you struggling with the syntax for declaring a pre-initialized hash table directly?   `$h = @{ "c" = "A P L"; "R" = "6h" ,,, }`

Comment: Input will be read from a file.

Comment: If you're writing the file from PowerShell, also consider using one of the Export-* cmdlets - then reading the content back in can be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Your string is being piped into `ForEach-Object` (`%`) as a whole string. There's no part of your code that splits it into lines, so it won't be processed line by line. As a result you get a datastructure like this:

```
{
  'c': [ "APL`nR", "6h`nH", "HN-56-78`nL", "binary`nE", "m@a.com" ]
}
```

Split the string into lines before splitting each line at colons to avoid this:

```
$h=@{}
@"
c : A P L
R : 6h
H : HN-56-78
L : binary
E : m@a.com
"@ -split "\r?\n" | %{ $v,$k = $_ -replace ' ' -split '\s*:\s*' ; $h.Add($v,$k) }
$h.Count
```

I've also integrated Ansgar's suggestion into your other split, putting `\s*` on either side of the `:`. That will catch any and all whitespace as part of the delimiter, and not include it in your resulting values.